# Computer networking dwdm

Tags: protocol-theory, transport-protocol

Why do we use digital cross connects, which define permanent cross connect between source and destination in core network while the PSTN allocated circuits dynamically as both are types of circuit switching?

Answer (score 1):

When referring to circuit switching, we mean the end-to-end circuit for which the two end-points have exclusive use during the call.

Patching a fiber jumper is not at all the same thing. First, it is a circuit between two communication devices, not two end-points. Next is is not for exclusive use of a call during the entire time it is established; multiple calls can share the link because they are broken up into packets, which is why it is packet switching, and the packets may have other paths between the two end-points.

In the early days of telephony, operators physically patched a call with a jumper on a board, and the circuit was completed with exclusive use from end-to-end until the call was finished, at which time the operator removed the jumper, breaking the circuit. No other calls used any part of the circuit.

Later on, computers replaced the manual patching with automated patching, but the way a circuit was completed was still a full circuit for exclusive use by the two end-points for the duration of the call.

Circuit switching is wasteful of physical resources, so multiplexing was introduced to make better use of the infrastructure, then packet switching came into general use, and the telcos are all moving toward using that because it allows even more calls over the same physical infrastructure.

With packet switching, the call is broken down into discrete packets that can be sent over any path between the two end-points, and any link in any of the paths may be shared among many different calls. The path may change as conditions on the network change, or multiple paths between the two end-points may simultaneously be used for a single call. There is no concept of a single end-to-end circuit with exclusive use by a call.

Your "*digital cross connect which define permanent cross connect*" is not exclusive to two end-points, and it may not be the only way to get between the two end-points.

Comment: But pstn allcotes circuit dynamically means when subscriber calls to other subscriber while SDH has permenant cross connect which cannot be used by others even not in use

Comment: PSTN creates a circuit between the two end-points that is dedicated to a call, and is switched as different calls are made. The patch cable in your data closet is _not_ dedicated to any particular call, and you do not go into the closet and change it when you create or drop a call because it is not dedicated to any one call for any length of time. Packets from many different calls travel over it in its permanent (non-switched) position. You do not move (switch) the patch cable to change calls the way PSTN moves (switches) circuits as you make and drop calls.

Comment: I m not talking about physical patch cord crossc9nneCt i m asking about sdh or sonet crossc9nneCt in ADM

Comment: You are confused because SONET can carry packets from many different sources going to many different destinations. We have a lot of SONET circuits over which we send all the packets from all the hosts/applications from one site to hosts/applications at many other sites.

Comment: But sonet has predefined cross connect which cannot be used by other circuits once it is fixed for any one circuit

Comment: That is my point. It is _not_ circuit switched as you have in your question, but it is packet switched, as I have tried to explain. You _do not_ move the patch (either physically or logically) to change source/destination end-points.