# Can we run the Internet on circuit switching?

Tags: switching, internet, networking

Generally we use IP and ATM for data communication and can we use circuit switching for data communication ?

Can we use circuit switching for Internet ?

Comment: This sounds like you're asking for something related to a class you're in, correct?  We already went through practically the [same discussion](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/51127/775 "Circuit switching with DWDM") with you

Comment: You might want to let your instructor know that ATM is almost extinct in modern core data networks.  This question was basically obsolete 10 years ago and was only relevant ~20 years ago.  As a thought experiment try running the numbers for a few billion end hosts calling for new connections potentially a dozen or more times per *second* and consider how much state information would be required to be maintained on how many devices.  It's orders of magnitude beyond what present-day voice networks carry.  Packet switching won for a reason.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just to make sure we're all on the same page, a circuit-switched network is a network in which a path is dynamically allocated for the dedicated purpose of a single conversation, then released back into the available pool once the conversation is over.  A great example of this would be the telephone network.

Here's probably **one** of the chief reasons that a circuit-switched network would be a bad solution for the internet: bandwidth.

On the phone network, each phone call is exactly the same "width".  You know, the call is dedicated to you whether you are speaking or not.  Silence is wasteful because you're occupying a path and not talking.   And the frequency range that the human ear can hear is 20hz-20khz (but the phone doesn't capture all of that, nor does the phone call transport all of that).  If you wanted to transmit the sound of a dog whistle through the phone, you're out of luck.

In contrast, on the internet, some conversations have very low demand, where others have very high demands.  If you were to run the internet on a circuit-switched network, you would have to ensure that every path met the highest requirements of every conversation (like being able to transmit a dog whistle), or the alternative is to limit the capabilities of the highest power-users (which is why the phone network does NOT transmit dog whistles).  Catering to the highest requirements would be very wasteful.

Therefore, since the internet is packet-switched, we have the luxury of using tiny amounts of bandwidth to some places, and large amounts of bandwidth to other places, and shifting all that around dynamically (even within a single session) without having to occupy dedicated paths and waste lots of bandwidth!  Isn't it great?

Answer (score 3):

> Can we run internet on circuit switching?

The Internet uses IP (Internet Protocol), which is a *packet switching* protocol. The Internet uses packet switching, not circuit switching.

Circuit switching is very wasteful of resources because it dedicates an end-to-end circuit to a call, where packet switching can use a circuit for many, many different calls. Even the telcos are moving away from circuit switching to packet switching for voice calls.

Answer (score 3):

> Can we use circuit switching for internet ?

In theory, we could. Actually, we used to - the very first Internet connections were modem links using the telephone network, a circuit-switched infrastructure. Classic modem dial-up used the same telephone network for at least part of the path.

IP is a generally packet-based protocol. Running it on top of a circuit-switched network creates an overlay network. Effiency-wise this gets you the worst of both worlds combined.

Packet-switched networks have two huge advantages: they are much more efficient and they can be upgraded much more easily, leading to cheaper networks that provide much more bandwidth, evolve faster, and scale better. This led to a parallel deployment of packet-switched networks at first that have all but taken over the circuit-switched applications by now.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of running circuit switching with internet cannot be logicaly implmented 
example: you are sending a sms to your friend in usa and you are in uk 
the idea of circuit switching it will establish a  private route for all your messages between you and your friend 
overall  what if 2 million people are texting at same time 
2 million routes are established  this is  un logical use for the internet  network  the internet network  main goal is to connect any person from any place with others   in a fair speed of accessing the network
so if you using circuit switching this is  inefficient use of your network because you will be consuming bandwidth of network in  establishig the route 
other point what if the route failed for any reason 
what is the cost of your resources to restbalish the rohte again

circuit switching ensures  that if a message is sent from point A it will be recieved  in point B  this will come over speed of sending and recieving and resources of the network 
packet switching  says that packets are sent in any route 
and no ensure that all packets will be recieved by point B